# Automated compilation python script when computer is off

Tags: python-3.x, cron, scheduler

I have a Python script which works and I have to compile it one time by week Wednesday at 2pm.

I'm at the moment in an internship and it's going to end tomorrow. So, I really have to automate the process because when I'll leave, the computer will be turned off and I don't know if it's possible to run Python script and stock results in Excel when it's off.

I saw things about scheduler and cron but it doesn't work when computer is off.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it's not possible to run scripts while the computer is switched off. The instances which you may have heard of were when people submit the cron job to a server, have it running there and have the data written to a shared folder.

Comment: Thank you ! I wasn't sure about that.